# Google Chrome Tab Search is Not Working

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

So, I just bought a new laptop, installed Google Chrome, and discovered to my dismay that when I try to do what I normally do to perform a search, Google Chrome is acting wonky.

To normally search on every other computer I use, I start typing google in the adress bar, when I get to goo (usually), I'll hit TAB to enter "site search mode". Chrome is being a jerk and trying to take me to a page that is in my history.

I've tried clearing my history to see if that would fix it, but it still won't seem to work.

So, what can I do to make "search in site" work for Google (when it works by default for every other installation of Chrome)?

Comment: You know, you can just type a search into the bar without "goo" or anything in front of it? http://i.imgur.com/Wfk8i.png

Comment: I know, it's just a habit that I can't seem to break. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to chrome://settings/ then **Manage Search Engines** and in order for feature to work it must be added to the list of search engines. Chrome typically adds it automatically once you visit the site though.

Comment: Tab search in Chrome stopped working for a site that had previously worked. I removed the site from the list and visited it again. Works again. I assume the site changed and chrome was using an old URL or something.

Comment: For me tab moves focus from address bar.

Comment: Thesarus.com stopped working and neither adding it manually nor visiting the website did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome, visit [chrome://settings/searchEngines](http://chrome://settings/searchEngines)
...You will see a list of all the tab-activated search engines, which Chrome has collected.

I will assume the search engine you want is NOT listed. If your engine IS listed [a problem I have NOT encountered], it may help to delete it, and re-add it using the following instructions:

Click [Add]

```
Search Engine: <Any friendly name you like>
Keyword      : <What you type in the URL bar to activate the search feature>
URL          : <The search URL with "%s" where your search words must appear>
```

Example ...I recently enabled the Youtube dark theme, which broke the Youtube "tab search" in Chrome:

```
Search Engine: Youtube
Keyword      : youtube
URL          : https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s
```

Click [Add] (again)

If you do not know what the search URL should look like: Go to the website in question, perform a search, and look at what ends up in the URL bar ...Your text will be "URL Encoded", EG. spaces will be replaced by +'s (etc) - do not worry about that, the URL encoding will be done by Chrome's search engine for you :)

Example.
Go to Amazon and perform a search for "eneloop AA" which (for me) generates this URL:

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=eneloop+AA&ref=nb_sb_noss_1
...You might notice that if you remove the "&ref..." from the end, the search still works

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=eneloop+AA
...So our Search engine URL could be:

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=%s

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me.

Comment: This is dumb, but this comment helped me realize that I was only putting "%" not "%s" in the link. The "s" is important, apparently!

Answer (score 3):

Problem: I did what I always do, go to the Chrome web address bar at the top of the screen, typed "w" and "TAB"...but suddenly it did not allow me to search Wikipedia, which I do many times every day.

Solution: I hit the "3 dots" at the top right of the screen to get to "Settings", then clicked "Search Engine" on the left and scrolled down to "Inactive Shortcuts".  Found "Wikipedia.org" and clicked "Activate" and it worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I disagree with the community bot post- this answer is perfectly adequate and solved my issue. Trying to add a new Youtube.com shortcut kept saying it was failing. No idea why! Then I saw this answer and realised the issue is that it already exists but has been deactivated for whatever reason. Cheers @MontyCircus

Comment: This is the *only* answer that worked for me in 2024. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`
- Site search `add button`
- Enter this details in `Edit search engine dialog box`

1. **Search engine**: `YouTube`
2. **Shortcut:** `youtube.com`
3. **URL with %s in place of query:** `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s&page={startPage?}&utm_source=opensearch`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and this worked for me:

Go to chrome://settings/searchEngines

At the bottom there are probably entries under "Inactive shortcuts"

you can make them usable again by clicking the "Activate" button on the right